# When I run pip install tkinter, an error is showing up

Tags: python, tkinter, pip

when I run the command, pip install tkinter, this shows up:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tkinter (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tkinter
```

in red colour. Any idea why this is happening?

tkinter code I wrote:

```
from tkinter import *

win = Tk()

def btn1():
  print("I Don't Know Your Name")

button1 =  Button(win, text="Click Me To Print SomeThing", command=btn1)

button1.pack()
win.mainloop()
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can't install tkinter with pip. It comes with python.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Btkinter%5D+install